# Relative frequency in r by factor

Tags: r, statistics, frequency, tapply

I would like to get a table of top 10 absolute and relative frequencies for a variable across other factor variable.
I have a dataframe with 3 columns: 1 column is a factor variable, 2nd is other variable I need to count, 3 is logical variable as a constraint. (real database has more than 4mln observations)

```
dtf<-data.frame(c("a","a","b","c","b"),c("aaa","bbb","aaa","aaa","bbb"),c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE))
colnames(dtf)<-c("factor","var","log")
dtf

factor var   log
1      a aaa  TRUE
2      a bbb FALSE
3      b aaa  TRUE
4      c aaa  TRUE
5      b bbb  TRUE
```

So I need to find top absolute and relative frequencies of "var" where "log"==TRUE across each factor of "factor".

I've tried this with absolute frequencies (in real db I extract top 10, here I get 2 lines):

```
t1<-tapply(dtf$var[dtf$log==T],dtf$factor[dtf$log==T],function(x)(head(sort(table(x),decreasing=T),n=2L)))
# Returns array of lists: list of factors containing list of top frequencies
t2<-(t1, ldply)
# Split list inside by id and freq
t3<-do.call(rbind, lapply(t2, data.frame))
# Returns dataframe of top "var" values and corresponding freq for each group in "factor"
# Factor variable's labels are saved as row.names in t3
```

The following function helps to find relative frequency as for the whole database, not grouped by factors:

```
getrelfreq<-function(x){
v<-table(x)
v_rel<-v/nrow(dtf[dtf$log==T,])
head(sort(v_rel,decreasing=T),n=2L)}
```

But I have problems with relative frequencies as I need to divide the absolute frequency by number of rows of "var" BY EACH factor, not TOTAL nrow of "var" where "log"==T. I don't know how to use that in tapply loop such that the denominator will be different for each factor.
I also would like to use both functions in 1 tapply loop instead of generating many tables and merging results. But have no idea how to put such 2 functions together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can do something like what I have written below. Use `dcast` to get the frequencies of each `var` across each `factor`, then use `rowSums()` to add them up to get absolute frequencies for each var across all factors. You can use `prop.table` to work out the relative frequency of each `var` across each `factor`. Note I made a slight change to your example data so you can follow what is happening at each stage (I added a `'bbb'` value for `factor` `b` when `log == TRUE` ). Try this:

```
#Data frame (note 2 values for 'bbb' for factor 'b' when log == TRUE)
dtf<-data.frame(c("a","a","b","c","b","b"),c("aaa","bbb","aaa","aaa","bbb","bbb"),c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE))
colnames(dtf)<-c("factor","var","log")
dtf
#     factor var   log
#1      a aaa  TRUE
#2      a bbb FALSE
#3      b aaa  TRUE
#4      c aaa  TRUE
#5      b bbb  TRUE
#6      b bbb  TRUE


library(reshape2)

# Find frequency of each var across each factor using dcast
mydat <- dcast( dtf[dtf$log==TRUE , ] , var ~ factor , sum )
#  var a b c
#1 aaa 1 1 1
#2 bbb 0 2 0

# Use rowSums to find absolute frequency of each var across all groups
mydat$counts <- rowSums( mydat[,-1] )
# Order by decreasing frequency and just use first 10 rows
mydat[ order( mydat$counts , decreasing = TRUE ) , ]
#  var a b c counts
#1 aaa 1 1 1      3
#2 bbb 0 2 0      2


# Relative proportions for each var across the factors
data.frame( var = mydat$var , round( prop.table( as.matrix( mydat[,-c(1,ncol(mydat))]) , 1 ) , 2 ) )
#  var    a    b    c
#1 aaa 0.33 0.33 0.33
#2 bbb 0.00 1.00 0.00
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for a clue! 
But I have a problem with my data, my "var" is also factor variable with more than 6000 levels in it, so my mydat will be very huge. But I guess it will take the same systime as for just getting top 10 frequencies? I don't know how to get counts other than your method, so have no options :)

Comment: @Asayat Well I guess you have to compute all the frequencies (near enough) to find the top 10. Try it out - If it crashes your computer then we need to find another way! :-) How many rows of data do you have? And how many different variables in factor? `unqiue(dtf$factor)`

Comment: It's total 3,221,155 rows, subsetting the dtf with only log=TRUE will result 1,222,490 rows. dtf$factor has 16 different values, dtf$var has 6421 unique values. 
Sorry for the late response, have issues with my RAM now :)

Comment: @Asayat are you on Windows? And are you using 64bit or 32 bit R? 1.2e6 rows is a lot, but definitely handleable in R, especially as you are creating a dataframe with <100,000 rows.

Comment: I'm on mac now, think it's just my laptop issues, perhaps it's too old for such things. But I can try on other computer in 12hours at my office (sorry for misunderstanding, I had more powerful pc when asked for question, but not now, timezones issues, will be back in office in 12hours :)). I guess your answer will be perfect one, as R computes all frequencies anyhow, so probably there won't be any other method that computes less than that