# R mutate to calculate relative frequency of occurrence within groups

Tags: r, tidyverse

I need some help.

Let's say that I have this:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   a         b c    
   <chr> <dbl> <lgl>
 1 a         1 TRUE 
 2 a         1 TRUE 
 3 a         1 TRUE 
 4 a         2 TRUE 
 5 a         2 TRUE 
 6 a         2 FALSE
 7 a         2 FALSE
 8 a         3 FALSE
 9 a         3 FALSE
10 a         3 FALSE

structure(list(a = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a"), b = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), c = c(TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to `group_by` column `b` and calculate within each group the relative frequency of `T == TRUE` in column `c` to generate the column `d`.

So I want this output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   a         b c         d
   <chr> <dbl> <lgl> <dbl>
 1 a         1 TRUE    1  
 2 a         1 TRUE    1  
 3 a         1 TRUE    1  
 4 a         2 TRUE    0.5
 5 a         2 TRUE    0.5
 6 a         2 FALSE   0.5
 7 a         2 FALSE   0.5
 8 a         3 FALSE   0  
 9 a         3 FALSE   0  
10 a         3 FALSE   0  

structure(list(a = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a"), b = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), c = c(TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), d = c(1, 
1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Preferable with `dplyr` or `tidyverse`.

I tried:

```
#1
t %>% 
  group_by(b) %>%
  mutate(
    d = nrow(c[c == T])/nrow()
  )
#2
t %>% 
  group_by(b) %>%
  mutate(
    d = count(c[c == T])/count()
  )
#3 
t %>% 
  group_by(b) %>%
  mutate(
    d = nrow(any(c[c == T]))/nrow(any())
  )
```

Neither one worked.

Similar questions (but different):
[How to calculate the relative frequency per groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41151016/how-to-calculate-the-relative-frequency-per-groups)
[R: relative frequency in r by factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16035614/r-relative-frequency-in-r-by-factor)

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of those "similar questions" (and probably others) , in my opinion. Not sure why it was reopened.

Comment: @neifws  The OP already mentioned in the post that it is not a dupe on his opinion `Similar questions (but different):`

Comment: @neilfws I opened it because I judged it as a new question or more specific enough since I couldn't use any other to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just take the `mean` of 'c' after grouping by 'b'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(b) %>% 
    mutate(d = mean(c))
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   b [3]
#   a         b c         d
#   <chr> <dbl> <lgl> <dbl>
# 1 a         1 TRUE    1  
# 2 a         1 TRUE    1  
# 3 a         1 TRUE    1  
# 4 a         2 TRUE    0.5
# 5 a         2 TRUE    0.5
# 6 a         2 FALSE   0.5
# 7 a         2 FALSE   0.5
# 8 a         3 FALSE   0  
# 9 a         3 FALSE   0  
#10 a         3 FALSE   0
```

NOTE: `mean` - definition - the "average" you're used to, where you add up all the numbers and then divide by the number of numbers.

---

Another option is

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(b) %>%
   mutate(d = sum(as.integer(c))/n())
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, d := mean(c), by = b]
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df1$d <- with(df1, ave(c, b))
```

Comment: So easy, thank you a lot. Perhaps, it were a really fast answer. I need to wait 6 minutes to vote. :D

Comment: And If I want to count in a char column how may are `!= NA_character_`

Comment: @AurelianoGuedes  What is `Cha`.  If it is a string, then `df1 %>%group_by(b) %>% mutate(e = sum(!is.na(col)))`

Comment: @AurelianoGuedes  With `NA` whether it is `NA_real_`, or `NA_integer_` or `NA_character_`, the `is.na` works for all of these which return a TRUE/FALSE logical vector and from there, you can get the `sum` of the vector where the TRUE is encoded as 1 and FALSE 0

Answer (score 2):

Usually to find number of times a variable occurs in a group we do

```
df %>%
  group_by(b) %>%
  mutate(d = sum(c == TRUE)/n())
```

but since here `c` is logical vector we could also take `sum` of `c` and then divide by number of rows in the group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(b) %>%
  mutate(d = sum(c)/n())

#   a         b c         d
#   <chr> <dbl> <lgl> <dbl>
# 1 a         1 TRUE    1  
# 2 a         1 TRUE    1  
# 3 a         1 TRUE    1  
# 4 a         2 TRUE    0.5
# 5 a         2 TRUE    0.5
# 6 a         2 FALSE   0.5
# 7 a         2 FALSE   0.5
# 8 a         3 FALSE   0  
# 9 a         3 FALSE   0  
#10 a         3 FALSE   0
```